# Unity side bar freeze bug

Tags: 11.04, unity, freeze

I just installed ubuntu 11.04 and the side bar of the unity interface tends to freeze after a certain period of time and I can only fix it by restartyng the computer. What is the cause? or is it just a bug that will be fixed in the future?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

This was, in fact, a bug and I believe it should be fixed now.  It is definitely fixed in 11.10.